# Swipe animation to go with gesture

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, backbone.js

I would like to implement a swipe gesture to replace the current Next/Prev-buttons in my web app. I figure I'll use either jQuery Mobile, QuoJS or Hammer.js to recognize the swipe gestures.

**But how can I go about implementing the swipe animation (similar to [this](http://www.awwwards.com/demo/touchSwipe-gallery-demo.html)) to go with the gestures?**

I'm not flipping between images as in the example, but html sections mapping onto Backbone Model Views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This finally "solved" it. I'm using jQuery-UI with a slide effect, but it's not looking as good as I had hoped, I want it to look more like on iOS using Obj-C. But it will have to do.

```
var handleSwipeEvents = function() {
    $(function() {
        $('#myId').on('swipeleft', swipeHandler);
        $('#myId').on('swiperight', swipeHandler);
        function swipeHandler(event) {
            function slideEffect(swipeLeft, duration) {
                var slideOutOptions = {"direction" : swipeLeft ? "left": "right", "mode" : "hide"};
                $('#myId').effect("slide", slideOutOptions, duration, function() { // slide out old data
                    var slideInOptions = {"direction" : swipeLeft ? "right" : "left", "mode" : "show"};
                    $('#myId').effect("slide", slideInOptions, duration); // slide in new data
                    // Alter contents of element
                });
            }
            var swipeLeft = (event.type === "swipeleft");
            slideEffect(swipeLeft, 300);
        }
    });
};
```

I have a feeling one can achieve better results using CSS3 and transition, but I haven't succeeded with that.